# How to detect outliers documents using python Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, python

I'm currently working on a Machine Learning project. The point of this project is to train a model with a `pandas.Dataframe` composed with 3 columns:

- "Libellé pays" --> that won't be used for now.
- "Marchandise"  --> current strings that I want to use.
- "label"        --> corresponding labels

The thing is, I have only one "class" of document (labelled 1). I would like
to have at the end a model that will be able to determine if a document could be identified as similar to the trained datasets.
After some research, I was able to tell that outliers detection could be useful, but I can't find documentation that matches my current problem.

Could you help me with that?

**Edit** : adding code and data.

```
def class MLModel:

    def __init__(self, logger):
    """MLModel constructor."""

    self.logger = logger
    self.xml_dir = "./DASCP-DASCV_2018_MRS-FOS.xls"
    self.dataframe = None
    self.classifier = None


def get_traindata_from_xls(self):
    """fetch training data from excell file. filepath is in init"""

    xl = pd.ExcelFile(self.xml_dir)
    self.dataframe = xl.parse('Manifest')
```

and this is what `self.dataframe` looks like: https://pastebin.com/faduQ6gU

```
Libellé Pays    object
Marchandise     object
label            int64
dtype: object
```